# Using code with same name in a module

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheets("Guide").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A9").Select
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnKey "%{F11}", "DisableAltF11"
Application.OnKey "%{F8}", "DisableAltF8"
End Sub
```

I an having this two codes which has identical name due to which the code doesn't run properly what can i change the name with so that it goes in flow
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheets("Guide").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A9").Select
    Application.OnKey "%{F11}", "DisableAltF11"
    Application.OnKey "%{F8}", "DisableAltF8"
End Sub
```

Just combine these two subs into one.

Comment: Thanks Buddy.....But by this neither of the code runs           Is there any other way with you can guide me like allotting a different name to anyone of the code...

Comment: In order to make it work you must place the code it in 'ThisWorkbook' - not in regular module.

VBAProject/Microsoft Excel Objects/ThisWorkbook

Comment: Yep both the codes are in "This Workbook" only and being macros having same name it shows an error of Ambiguous name detected : Workbook_Open. Can i  name one macro as Workbook_Open() and the other one as Workbook_Open1() ?

Comment: Search your project to find all subs with this name and combine them into one. If these 2 subs you presented above are the only one then remove them and use what I posted. It should work.

Comment: _Can i name one macro as Workbook_Open() and the other one as Workbook_Open1()_  Yes you can.  The one that stays as `Workbook_Open()` will run when you open the workbook (with macros enabled).  `Workbook_Open1() ` will never run unless you tell it to.  If you write `Workbook_Open1()` just before the `End Sub` in `Workbook_Open` then it will run that code after it's run the first set.  The code given by @FunkyMonkX will work if you delete one of the procedures (so you don't get the Ambiguous name).